# spring boot Failed 'url' attribute is not specified

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, maven, spring-data-jpa

application.yml in a module with main class and hibernate:

```
## JDBC part
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: local
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/kazi?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    username: emo
    password: 123qwe
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
  liquibase:
    change-log: classpath:liquibase/changelog.xml
  autoconfigure:
    exclude: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration
```

main pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.emo.kazi</groupId>
        <artifactId>kazi-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>kazi</artifactId>
    <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>kazi-core</module>
        <module>kazi-api</module>
        <module>kazi-service</module>
    </modules>

   <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
              <skip>true</skip>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

my module pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.emo.kazi</groupId>
        <artifactId>kazi</artifactId>
        <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>kazi-core</artifactId>
    <version>${parent.version}</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>kazi-core</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-jaxb-annotations</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

In the parent project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.emo.kazi</groupId>
    <artifactId>kazi-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- GrantedAuthority wird in kazi project bei Role verwendet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.16</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-plugin-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

Error:

```
2022-01-24 16:13:42.658  WARN 24223 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase]: Factory method 'liquibase' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
2022-01-24 16:13:42.659  INFO 24223 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2022-01-24 16:13:42.761  INFO 24223 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-01-24 16:13:42.781 ERROR 24223 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).


Process finished with exit code 0
```

[image]

Comment: im guessing u need to define `spring-boot-start-data` dependency in the module that uses it

Answer (score 1):

> Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class

The stacktrace says the exception happens when creating the `HikariDataSource` bean because it complains you do not define `driverClassName` or `url` for the JDBC connection in the properties file.

But creating this `HikariDataSource` bean is triggered by the `DataSourceAutoConfiguration` which you already exclude it explicitly in the properties file.

So I believe mostly probably there are some configuration issue that causes it cannot load your `application.yml` successfully (may be you put it in the wrong folder ?) Because if it can be loaded successfully , it will exclude `DataSourceAutoConfiguration` as configured and will not create `HikariDataSource` and will not throw this exception.

Comment: i started a new project and it works with `@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class)` but not only with `autoconfigure:
    exclude: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration`. 
I think the `application.yml` won't loaded. Some ideas why?

Comment: no idea without knowing your project structure

Comment: i added a picture with the structure. `Application` in `kazi-core` is the only main class

Comment: You run the Application using IDE? Can it be an IDE issue ? How about you use `mvn clean package` to package a JAR , and then directly execute the JAR . are there any differences ?

Comment: i tried it directly on terminal and same issue.

Comment: it works only with `@EnableAutoConfiguration`